# After setting an OnClickListener, my View does not show visual feedback that it was clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Further details:

If I do not set a OnClickListener on my View, Android seems to automatically handle the OnClick state of my View and changes the background of the view to show that it was clicked. Yet if I add an OnClickListener of my own, there is no visual change shown, is there something I need to call to show the state change?

This View is also found in a ListView (not sure if this helps though).

Here's how I set the OnClickListener on my View:

```
items.add(new EntryItem("Profile", R.drawable.ic_action_user, null,
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    self.closeDrawer();
                    Intent userView = new Intent(self,
                            UserViewActivity.class);
                    userView.putExtra("username", "kortank");

                    self.startActivity(userView);
                }

            }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This View is also found in a ListView (not sure if this helps though).

If you set a click listener for a list item, the listView's onClick listener for the list item(the one that changes the background and etc) is overriden. Try using the **ListView.setOnItemClickListener** instead.

Comment: @vivatus, if this solved your problem, please choose it as an aswer.

Comment: Had to wait two minutes before I could!